# Javascript/Jquery making text to fit perfectly on div given dimensions with line break(if needed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I'm having a little hard time working this out: I have these functions that I use in order to fit a single lined text into given dimensions.

```
function getFontSize(width, height, text, font, callback) {
    var n = 100;
    var ctxfont = n + 'px ' + font;
    var result = measureTextHeight(ctxfont, text);
    while (result.width > width || result.height > height) {
        n--;
        var ctxfont = n + 'px ' + font;
        var result = measureTextHeight(ctxfont, text);
    }
    callback({
        'width': result.width,
        'height': result.height,
        'size': n
    });
}

function measureTextHeight(ctxFont, text) {
    var width = 1500;
    var height = 500;

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.save();
    ctx.font = ctxFont;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.fillText(text, parseInt(width * 0.1, 10), parseInt(height / 2, 10));
    ctx.restore();
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    var data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data;


    var topMost = false;
    var bottomMost = false;
    var leftMost = false;
    var rightMost = false;
    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; (y < height) && (!leftMost); y++) {
            //console.log("x: %s y: %s index: %s", x,y, getAlphaIndexForCoordinates(x,y,width,height).toString() );
            if (data[getAlphaIndexForCoordinates(x, y, width, height)] != 0) {
                leftMost = x;
            }
        }
    }
    for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; (x < width) && (!topMost); x++) {
            //console.log("x: %s y: %s index: %s", x,y, getAlphaIndexForCoordinates(x,y,width,height).toString() );
            if (data[getAlphaIndexForCoordinates(x, y, width, height)] != 0) {
                topMost = y;
            }
        }
    }
    for (var x = width - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
        for (var y = height - 1; (y >= 0) && (!rightMost); y--) {
            //console.log("x: %s y: %s index: %s", x,y, getAlphaIndexForCoordinates(x,y,width,height).toString() );
            if (data[getAlphaIndexForCoordinates(x, y, width, height)] != 0) {
                rightMost = x;
            }
        }
    }
    for (var y = height - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
        for (var x = width - 1; (x >= 0) && (!bottomMost); x--) {
            //console.log("x: %s y: %s index: %s", x,y, getAlphaIndexForCoordinates(x,y,width,height).toString() );
            if (data[getAlphaIndexForCoordinates(x, y, width, height)] != 0) {
                bottomMost = y;
            }
        }
    }
    canvas.remove();
    return ({
        width: (rightMost - leftMost) + 1
        , height: (bottomMost - topMost) + 1
    });
}

function getAlphaIndexForCoordinates(x, y, width, height) {
    return (((width * 4 * y) + 4 * x) + 3);
}
```

I pass the wanted dimensions and font to getFontSize function and it returns the real width and height of the text as well as the font size needed for it to be accomplished. This way I can draw the text to canvas using ctx.filltext() function, the best fit possible, and align it in the center based on its width and height. I'm not sure if it's the most efficient way of achieving the wanted result but it's working.

What I want to do now is instead of making it single lined, I can set a given width and height for a div and then, giving the text, it would fit perfectly those dimensions adding line breaks if needed, and still return the real width and height of the text so I can draw it correctly to the canvas like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vkgjrd3e/ although in the fiddle it still has some space on the bottom of the div.

What I'm trying to achieve is the best fit possible for the text, given its font and its container dimensions; adding line breaks if needed.

Comment: what is your main problem??

Comment: @Sushil What I'm looking for is when I pass to the function the dimensions and the text, and it is too long, it automatically gets line-breaks if needed. Let's say I pass a big text to the function and the width and height of 200px. I want it to return me the right font size and the text with the line-breaks(if needed) for it to nicely fit the measure. My code is already doing that but it doesn't add line-breaks and that's where I'm stuck at. If I need to add long texts to the canvas it is only shrinking it until it fits one line. Check whats currently happening: https://jsfiddle.net/pqhudmj0/

Comment: @MarcielFonseca do you need something like this?? https://jsfiddle.net/bpyqfhaz/

Comment: @Sushil precisely. The text will be fetched from my API and then a given width and height will be passed to the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is probably to use the power of CSS instead of trying to do it yourself.

You can create a dummy div, append a <span> into it, and increase its font-size until it doesn't fit anymore.
The font-size before was the correct one.

Then, you can walk over this <span>'s textContent using a [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) object in order to get the line-breaks CSS will have generated. The Range API provides a convenient [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/getBoundingClientRect) method, allowing us to find where the cursor is. We just have to remember the last y position and when it changes, we know the character before was the last of the line.

There are some downsides with this technique though.

- In the DOM multiple space characters are compressed in a single one. CanvasContext API doesn't have the same behavior, so we need to get rid of these before parsing the text.
- The measures are made based on the containers bounding boxes, this means it doesn't check for the painted pixels, so you may have some characters overflowing (for instance Zalgo͚̠͓ͣ̔͐̽) and some others not fitting *perfectly* in the box (depending on the ascent and descents of each characters).
- ... *probably others.*

```js
function getBestFontSize(text, width, height, userstyles) {
  if(!text) return null;
  
  const cont = document.createElement('div');
  cont.classList.add('best-font-size-tester');
  const style = cont.style;

  if(typeof width === 'number') width += 'px';
  if(typeof height === 'number') height += 'px';
  Object.assign(style, {width, height}, userstyles);

  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.textContent = text;
  cont.appendChild(span);
  document.body.appendChild(cont);
  
  let size = 0;
  
  const max = cont.getBoundingClientRect();
  while(true) {
    style.fontSize = size + 'px';
    let rect = span.getBoundingClientRect();
    if(rect.bottom > max.bottom || rect.right > max.right) {
      // overflown
      size -= 1; // the correct size was the one before
      break;
    }
    size++;
  }
  if(size === 0) {
    // even at 0 it doesn't fit...
    return null;
  }
  // now we'll get the line breaks by walking through our text content
  style.fontSize = size + 'px';
  const lines = getLineBreaks(span.childNodes[0], max.top);
  // cleanup
  document.body.removeChild(cont);

  return {
    fontSize: size,
    lines: lines
  };
}

function getLineBreaks(node, contTop) {
  if(!node) return [];
  const range = document.createRange();
  const lines = [];
  range.setStart(node, 0);
  let prevBottom = range.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
  let str = node.textContent;
  let current = 1;
  let lastFound = 0;
  let bottom = 0;
  while(current <= str.length) {
    range.setStart(node, current);
    if(current < str.length -1)
      range.setEnd(node, current+1);
    bottom = range.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
    if(bottom > prevBottom) {
      lines.push({
        y: prevBottom - (contTop || 0),
        text: str.substr(lastFound , current - lastFound)
      });
      prevBottom = bottom;
      lastFound = current;
    }
    current++;
  }
  // push the last line
  lines.push({
    y: bottom - (contTop || 0),
    text: str.substr(lastFound)
  });

  return lines;
}

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
txt_area.oninput = e => {
  const input = txt_area.value
    .replace(/(\s)(?=\1)/g, ''); // remove all double spaces
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.translate(19.5,19.5);
  ctx.strokeRect(0,0,100,100);

  if(!input.length) return;
  const bestFit = getBestFontSize(input, 100, 100, {
    fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
    fontWeight: '600',
    textAlign: 'center'
  });
  // apply thesame options we passed
  ctx.font = '600 ' + bestFit.fontSize + 'px sans-serif';
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  // translate again because text-align: center
  ctx.translate(50.5,0);
  bestFit.lines.forEach(({text, y}) => ctx.fillText(text, 0, y));
};
txt_area.oninput();
```

```css
.best-font-size-tester {
  border: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txt_area">This is an example text to fit the div even with line breaks</textarea>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: That's some great stuff. What I was looking for. Is there a way to avoid overflowing characters with Accentuation and vertically centering small words? In your snippet if You type Á and a single word such as 'Testing', You can see that they wont be vertically centered, and the 'Á' accentuation will be out of the box, that will make my script wrongly measure the x and y for the result

Comment: @MarcielFonseca For the vertical-center, you could pass some style rules to the function's `userstyles` argument, for instance `display: 'flex', 'align-items': 'center'` [will do it](https://jsfiddle.net/t8z6rpL5/1/) . For the accented characters, unfortunately no, that's one of the downsides I talked about, the bounding boxes don't care of the painted content, they just look at the font's declared ascents and descents.

Comment: I see. Anyhow, that's what I was looking for, I'm accepting the answer, Thank You