# Stop increasing font-size when text meets boundary of box it is in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a slider to increase or decrease the font size of the text within a `<td>`.

What I would like to do is, using jQuery to stop my slider from increasing the size of the font when the text within the `<td>` hits the edges of the enclosing `<td>`.

This is the JavaScript I am using to adjust the size of the font with the slider

```
$( function() {
    var handle = $( "#custom-handle-bottom" );
    $( "#fontsliderbottom" ).slider({
        value:current_bottom_font_size,
        min: 0,
        max: 70,
        step: 1,
        create: function() {
            handle.text( $( this ).slider( "value" ) );
        },
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            handle.text( ui.value );

            $('.lowertext').css('font-size', ui.value+'px');

        }
    });
});
```

So, maybe some code that determines if the text within the `td.lowertext` is as wide or wider than the width of the `td.lowertext`?

Comment: related, if not dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54203800/3702797

Comment: @Kaiido Don't think it is a dupe, but definitely interesting.  May still be able to use it, but not to do what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: The link @Kaiido suggested works perfectly fine as a duplicate, and after you tried it out, and if it still doesn't do what you was looking for, come back with what you tried and post a new question.

Comment: And now you also got an answer, so a lot to choose from.

Comment: try this : https://jsfiddle.net/ksvqzaur/
Since this is marked as dupe, can't add an answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read size of text inside div you can use `offsetWidth` element property (you also need to set `max-width` in css to avoid auto-resize td element)

```js
var s=120, fid= setInterval(x=>
{ 
  if(box.offsetWidth>text.offsetWidth) { 
    text.style.fontSize = (++s/10)+'px';
  } else {
    clearInterval(fid);
  }
},10)
```

```css
#box { max-width: 200px; width:200px; height: 80px; background: yellow;}
#text { white-space: nowrap; }
```

```html
<table><body><tr>
  <td id='box' ><a href=# id=text>some text</a><td>
</tr></body></table>
```

Comment: Using the visible element is quite dangerous. If one day they decide to set this element as block or inline-block with a max-width, [then your code breaks](https://jsfiddle.net/yjg914Lp/). Better use a dummy element that your code does control entirely and search for the max value directly.