# How to know on which character of a string the rendered string is wider than a given width(so overflow occurs)?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I know we have `measureText` in canvas and get the width of any string. Sometimes, before I render a text on a canvas, I need to know where overflow occurs. I think I can do that with multiple calls of `measureText`. But it doesn't look efficient.

If there's a built-in method like `measureText` for what I'm asking(even draft only for now), that would be the best.

If there isn't, what is the common practice for this problem?

Comment: Move to HTML+CSS before rendering on your canvas, that's way more powerfull for text rendering. See also this related [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54203800/javascript-jquery-making-text-to-fit-perfectly-on-div-given-dimensions-with-line/54472418#54472418)  which was doing this. Both questions there were asking for line-breaks, so the code does check for it. In you case, you just have to set  `word-break: break-all` on the testing element, or check for `range.getBoundingClientRect.right > elem.getBoundingClient().right` instead of checking for the bottom position.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g3Lov29u/1/