# How to measure text with whitespace: pre on canvas?

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas, measure

You can measure text to get the width of a sentence like this:

```
ctx.measureText('I am a sentence').width
```

You can do this because you set the font on the context directly to match whatever CSS-styled text in your HTML that you're trying to *really* measure.

```
ctx.font = '24px MyFont';
```

But what if I want to apply `whitespace: pre` to the text? I seem to be getting weird results that don't measure up.

What I'm trying to do is simply calculate the words that can fit safely on a single line. That's it. But sometimes what I measure is smaller than what gets rendered, so I am starting to suspect that the canvas measurement technique isn't actually an accurate tool.

How do I accurately measure the width of a sentence taking into account all the features of the styling such as `letter-spacing`, `whitespace: pre`, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS and the Range API, which offers a [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/getBoundingClientRect) method, this is still the most powerful combination we have access to while waiting for the [Font metrics API](https://github.com/w3c/css-houdini-drafts/blob/master/font-metrics-api/README.md).

```js
const target = document.getElementById( 'target' );
const range = document.createRange();
const bounds = document.getElementById( 'bounds' );
range.selectNode( target.firstChild );
onresize = e => {
  const rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
  bounds.style.left = rect.x + 'px';
  bounds.style.top = rect.y + 'px';
  bounds.style.width = rect.width + 'px';
  bounds.style.height = rect.height + 'px';
};
onresize();
```

```css
#bounds {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<pre id="target">
Draw some     rect

around  
      me
</pre>
<div id="bounds"></div>
```

You can see a more complete example of this combination in order to draw on a canvas, probably more like you need, on [this related Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57403688/how-can-i-implement-word-wrap-and-carriage-returns-in-canvas-filltext/57404737#57404737).