# Split string in array on whitespace before the 10th character

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, canvas, text

I want to split a string into characters of 10. But I don't want to split inside a word.

So the string "Nine characters to go - then some more" would be split in `["Nine", "characters", "to go -", "then some", "more"]`.
The word can split if it's more than 10 characters.

The closest I got using regex was `.{1,10}(?<=\s)`.
That would split "Nine characters to go - then some more" into `["Nine ", "haracters ", "to go - ", "then some "]`.
But the behaviour is weird. In the example string it completely skips the character "c". In other test strings it would only add "- " in a separate array item when just the dash would fit in with the array item before it. So it splits after the whitespace.

I also attempted to `.split()` on white spaces (`.split(' ')`) and using `.reduce()` or a for loop to join array items into other array items of max 10 characters.

```
for ( i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++ ) {
  if ( i === 0 ) {
    // add first word in new array. Doesn't take into account yet that word can be longer than 10 characters
    newArray.push( splitArray[i] );
  } else {
    if ( newArray[ newArray.length - 1 ].length + splitArray[i].length + 1 < 10 ) {
      // if next word fits with the word in the new array (taking space into account), add it to it
      newArray[ newArray.length - 1 ] = newArray[ newArray.length - 1 ] + " " + splitArray[i];
    } else if ( newArray[ newArray.length - 1 ].length + splitArray[i].length + 1 >= 10 ) {
      // next word doesn't fit
      // split word and add only part to it and add the rest in separate item in newArray
      const index = 9 - newArray[ newArray.length - 1 ].length
      const prev = splitArray[i].slice( 0, index );
      const next = splitArray[i].slice( index, splitArray[i].length );
      newArray[ newArray.length - 1 ] = newArray[ newArray.length - 1 ] + " " + prev;
      newArray.push( next );
    } else {
      // push new item in newArray
      newArray.push( splitArray[i] );
    }
  }
}
```

Results in: `["Nine chara", "cters to g", "o - then s", "ome more"]`.
Without the `else if`: `["Nine", "characters", "to go -", "then some", "more"]`
Without the `else if` other string: `["Paul van", "den Dool", "-", "Alphabet", "- word"]`
This is close, but "Alphabet" won't join with the hyphen, because together they don't fit. I tried catching that with an `else if` statement but that is breaking words again that I don't want to break and is the same result as the regex above.

My mind is depleted on this issue, I need the hive mind for this. So any help on this is very much appreciated.

**Context**
I'm trying to display text on canvas in a limited sized box with a minimum font size. My solution would be to break the string, which can be entered by the user, into multiple lines if necessary. For this I need to split the string into an array, loop over it and position the text accordingly.

Comment: You got plenty of answer with algorithm to do the splitting... but keep in mind that not all letter have the same size in a canvas perhaps you should measure the text look into `measureText` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText you could be splitting on places that you really did not need to be split

Comment: That's very true. Did not yet think of that to be honest. But in full context, the text will be displayed in a square that will be displayed on a canvas on top of a webcam stream. The square will stick to your forehead. The square changes in size when you move your head, especially if you move your head forwards and backwards. So I think I'd have to add the text in canvas first to measure it and then do all the calculation to display it correctly. And that needs to update with the square which actually happens every 50ms. It might make that method heavier than I'd like I think.

Comment: Might help you in your original task: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54472418/3702797

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const string = "Nine characters to go - then some more"
let arr = string.split(" ");
for(let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i].length >= 10 || arr[i].length + arr[i-1].length >= 10) {
     continue;
  }
  if(arr[i].length < 10 && arr[i].length + arr[i-1].length <= 10) {
    arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + " " + arr[i];
    arr[i-1] = false;
  }

}
arr = arr.filter(string => string)

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Hi @Gendy, this is looking like a winner for me. This does not split up words that are longer than 10 characters but as other answer show, this can be troublesome as some array items in the middle of the array or the start can have one or just a few characters in them and that would look weird if put on separate lines in my project.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. to make the function shorter you can remove this lines `if(arr[i].length >= 10 || arr[i].length + arr[i-1].length >= 10) {
     continue;
  }` they are for demonstration more than doing logic.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```js
console.log(
  "Nine characters to go - then some more"
     .match(/.{1,10}(?=\s|$)/g)
     .map(z => z.trim())
);
```

With `.match(/.{1,10}(?=\s|$)/g)`, the items will be 1 to 10 characters long, and `(?=\s|$)` will assure a whitespace or end of string is matched.

Comment: Could you use `/(?<!\S).{1,10}(?=\s|$)/g` to avoid the trim step?

Comment: @Ryszard this seems to work for this string but adds the hyphen in its own array item in other test strings. It's definitely an improvement on mine, but other answer seem closer. I've created a test case with all answers on this post here: https://jsfiddle.net/35Lso9uv/

Comment: @CarySwoveland This seems to solve the "hyphen in its own array item" issue but if the word is longer than 10 characters its skipped (not added)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to split, use `.split()`:

```js
const str = 'Nine characters to go - then some more',
      
      result = str.split(/(.{1,10})\s/).filter(Boolean)
      
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I didn't know you could split on a regex! That's cool. I like the answer but a little downside is that if a word is longer than 10 characters (let's say 12) it adds the first two letters in its own array item and the rest in a second. I've created a little testing tools with all the answers here: https://jsfiddle.net/35Lso9uv/

Comment: @PaulvandenDool : Isn't that exactly what requirement in your original post reads (*'...The word can split if it's more than 10 characters'*)? If you were seeking for some other behavior, above method could be further adjusted, while staying just as neat. Anyways, the verbosity of accepted answer doesn't seem to be worth the complexity of the task ;)

Comment: It is indeed what I asked, but I didn't anticipate this behaviour and even though I love this solution, I'm stepping away from the splitting of words longer than 10 characters. And this all also made me realise both results aren't optimal for what I want in the end. Currently thinking about giving users a box where they can draw/write in. It will give the proper size constraints, allow me to drop any difficult splitting of strings and adds a nice element of the users' own handwriting where I already was going for a hand written effect with a font. So in the end, probably not using any of this.

Comment: @PaulvandenDool : above context mentioned at the very beginning could've saved you time as much more relevant options would be suggested. I'm not pushing towards my solution, but you should consider that having some long word un-split in the middle of your *paragraph* (stepping several characters out) would also look ugly. However, you're right, you need much smarter approach for word wrapping.

Comment: With this project, I'm learning as I go. I thought this was the way to go, but a good night sleep made me think otherwise. I didn't want to post some vague context and be like "give me solutions!". But I do very much appreciate you thinking with me. If you have any additional suggestions based on the full context I'm all ears :)

Answer (score 1):

I can solve this using a simple `for` loop:

```js
const str = "Nine characters to go - then some more";

// make an array with each words
const arr = str.trim().split(' ');

// This is the length, how much we want to take the length of the words
const length = 10;
const res = [];

/**
 * Put the first word into the result array
 * because if the word greater or less than
 * the `length` we have to take it.
 */
res.push(arr[0]);

// Result array's current index
let index = 0;

for (let i = 1, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
  /**
   * If the length of the concatenation of the
   * last word of the result array
   * and the next word is less than or equal to the length
   * then concat them and put them as the last value
   * of the resulting array.
   */
  if ((res[index] + arr[i]).length <= length) {
    res[index] += ' ' + arr[i];
  } else {
    /**
     * Otherwise push the current word
     * into the resulting array
     * and increase the last index of the
     * resulting array.
     */
    res.push(arr[i]);
    index++;
  }
}

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Comment: Hi Sajeeb! This answer works for me. It does not split up words that are longer than 10 characters, but other answers prove me that that can be troublesome.
This answer does the same as @Gendy's answer, but his one is a little less verbose (not counting comments).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I didn't see the other answer. And I was trying to keep the solution as clean and small as possible. BTW, it seemed your question is interesting to me.